# Recomposition of multiple Composables in loop

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have a simple question regarding the recomposition in Jetpack compose.
I want to implement a composeable that receives a List of something (the list may vary in size, here i assume it is fixed), and create a sub-composable out of every entry.

```
@Composable
fun MyGameComposable(mySomethingList: List<Something>) {
    for(something: Something in mySomethingList){
        SubComposable(something)
    }
}
```

I know that the composeables are composed on top of each other (and that's okay), but i want the 'top'-composable to be have a boolean flag (it has to react to user-input, the other ones shall stay dormant). I know that if the list is big in size, i should use a more 'recycable approach' - but i want to ignore that for now. Via a callback (when a certain user-input was done), I want to shift the boolean flag to the second composable (all but the second composable should stay dormant).

```
@Composable
fun MyGameComposable(mySomethingList: List<Something>) {
    for(something: Something in mySomethingList){
        SubComposable(something, isReactingToUserInput, ()->shiftReactToUserInputToNext())
    }
}
```

Now i have three questions (the first one does not directly regard recomposition):

1. Where should i define the boolean 'isReactingToUserInput'? I want it to be set true for the top composable, false for any other at the beginning. As soon as the first composable triggers, the second one becomes active, then the third etc.
2. When shiftReactToUserInputToNext() is triggered, how does recomposition work?
   Does it iterate through the whole list and update every isReactingToUserInput-value? That seems really time-consuming, assuming it has to create every sub-composable anew.
3. In my approach, all Composables will remain in the list (no matter what their active/dormant-status is). How could I implement that the composable that triggered shiftReactToUserInputToNext() not only sets another one 'active', but also gets removed from the list. This probably relates to question 2) : If i remove something from the list, does compose iterate over all remaining items again and has to create everything again.

The thing is: I want thisto be very responsive.That's also why the MyGameComposable receives the entire list directly. The creation of the 100 of Composables on top of each other can take some time (no problem for me), but i don't want compose to do that every time something changes.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [LazyColumn](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyColumn(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Function1)) and [LazyListState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState).

Comment: You can maintain what you are calling as `shiftReactToUserInput` in the LazyListState updating it when needed. This will trigger the recomposition lazily as the list state is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you a little bit more? How does recomposition work then?

Comment: As far as i read about LazyListState it is only usable for scrollable input, but mine is similar to a dating app, where one can swipe the matchcards - there is no scrolling involved

Comment: Building app which is similar to tinder using compose is a very simple use case that can be done using LazyColumns. Refer [TinderLike](https://github.com/cyph3rcod3r/Tinder-Like/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/tinder/ui/composables/FavouritesUi.kt). You might not need to overkill for controls and states. In this case study of TinderLike, the recomposition happens only for the top card whenever a user interaction is encountered and handled.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment! The App is indeed very interesting and was helpful in a lot of other problems i had (although i want to implement the swip-feature myself). I still fail to see how the arrangement in LazyColumns seems to fit to my problem. I tried using LazyColumns, and they work...but in my trial, the items are laid out...well, in columns! not on top of each other :/